# Passing HTML dropdown-menu values to HTML input through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid, queryselector

I am trying to create an HTML dropdown-menu that would send its value to other HTML input tags through Javascript before being sent to Coinpayment by POST method.
Obviously...something's not working, "itemval" and "amountval" don't seem to get the value from Javascript.

```js
 function initCP() {
 var itemOptions = document.querySelector("#item-options");
 switch(itemOptions) {
                     case "1": getElementById("itemval").innerHTML = "LIVE SESSION - 1 participant - 120 USD";
                               getElementById("amountval").innerHTML = "120";
                               break;

                     case "2": getElementById("itemval").innerHTML = "LIVE SESSION - 2 participants - 60 USD";
                               getElementById("amountval").innerHTML = "60";
                               break;

                     case "3": getElementById("itemval").innerHTML = "LIVE SESSION - 3 participant - 40 USD";
                               getElementById("amountval").innerHTML = "40";
                               break;

                     case "4": getElementById("itemval").innerHTML = "LIVE SESSION - 4 participants - 30 USD";
                               getElementById("amountval").innerHTML = "30";
                               break;
                              }}
```

```html
<form action="https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php" method="post">
<select onchange="initCP()" id="item-options">
 <option  value="1" price="120">LIVE SESSION - 1 participant - 120 USD</option>
 <option  value="2" price="60">LIVE SESSION - 2 participants - 60 USD</option>
 <option  value="3" price="40">LIVE SESSION - 3 participants - 40 USD</option>
 <option  value="4" price="30">LIVE SESSION - 4 participants - 30 USD</option></select>
<select style="visibility: hidden" id="quantitySelect"></select> 

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="itemval">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amountf" value="amountval">
<input type="image" src="https://www.coinpayments.net/images/pub/CP-third-large.png" alt="Buy Now with CoinPayments.net">
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are switching the element not its value.

The code will looks like this

```
function initCP() {
    var inpItemVal = document.getElementById(‘itemval’);
    var inpAmountVal = document.getElementById(‘amountval’);
    var value = document.getElementById(‘item-options’).value;
    switch(value) {
        case “1”: 
            inpItemVal.value = ‘...’;
            inpAmountVal.value = ‘...’;
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

And don’t forget the id tag:

ie:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id=“itemval” value="itemval">
<input type="hidden" name="amountf" id=“amountval” value="amountval">
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting closer, from the debug, I can see that the item-option is passing the right value.

Comment: And after spotting a missing bracket, this is finally working. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome. Edited the missing bracket too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just made the following modification:

```
console.log({itemOptions});
switch(itemOptions.value) {
```

It will fix and provide you a very simple way to debug by yourself.

Then you'll probably need to fix the `getElementById is not defined` with

```
document.getElementById
```

Then put the missing ids on inputs that you reach by id.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" id="itemval" value="itemval">
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="amountf" id="amountval" value="amountval">
```

Then use `.value` to set value on input, not `.innerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById(XXX).value
```

Comment: Thanks! I edited the script but still get the 'ERROR: No 'amountf' set in the button or amount is <= 0 (and allow_amount is set to 0)!'
Is the triggering event "onchange" accurate?

Comment: There is no button here and no way this error can pop from provided code.

Comment: I corrected a common mispell: getElementbyId to getElementById (and thus edited the original question). I can now see some changes in the console but it is still not passing values to itemval and amountval.

Comment: You should close this question and open another one, with the php code and the request done by the browser.

Comment: I meant that I have no control over the displayed error messages since they are delivered by the remote php file.
My issue remains valid. If I don't use the dropdown menu and javascript and assign a value directly in the input, this is working just fine.